# FBX model showing Black textures on ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I try to load this FBX model on ThreeJS.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pwa31xkia8tg8v9/fbx%20threejs.zip?dl=0

it's loading correctly with animation, but all are showing black texture.

I'm using official example to load FBX from ThreeJS, i just replaced model file.

Please help, i need this for my project.

Thanks for your time!
Regards

Comment: Show images of your problem, don't expect someone to download your file and open it. Are the UV coordinates on the model correct? Is the texture file being found? Have you checked for errors in the browser console?

Comment: Have you added a light to your scene???

Answer (score 1):

[FBX showing black texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu5qz.png)

i have added light to scene.

```
        light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444, 1.0);
        light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
        scene.add(light);

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
        light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
        scene.add(light);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file format of texture image. Convert the image to jpg and change your model likewise opening it in a text file. You can also check specific loader for specific image file format like TGALoader for .tga.